# Is Coercivity preserved under expectation?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis

Let $f(x) = \mathbb{E}[F(x, \omega)]$ where $F(., \omega)$ is a positive, convex and coercive function. It's straightforward to prove that $f$ is also positive and convex. However, I couldn't prove whether or not it is coercive.

If $f$ is not coercive in general, what conditions needed on $F$ to make sure $f$ is coercive?

Comment: What di you mean by coerciveness?

Comment: g(.) is called coercive if $g(y) \to \infty$ as $|y| \to \infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can prove, in your hypothesis, coerciveness:

Simply observe that $\omega \to F(x, \omega)$ is a family of non negative functions. Assume that $f$ is not coercive, you find a posive $M \in \mathbb{R}$ and a sequence $|x_n| \to \infty$ with $f(x_n) < M$.

Using fatou's lemma:

$M > \liminf E[F(x_n, \omega)] \ge E[\liminf F(x_n, \omega)] = \infty$

Answer (score 0):

In your setup I think the answer should be yes, but I have to assume that $\mathbb E[f(x,\omega)]$ is well-defined for all $x\in\mathbb R$ (i.e. it is finite). Then by convexity and positivity, there exists some $b<0$, and $a(\omega)>0$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$ such that $F(x,\omega)\ge a(\omega)x+b$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Then one has
$$\mathbb E[F(x,\omega)]=\int_\Omega F(x,\omega)\,d\mu(\omega)\ge \int_\Omega [a(\omega)x+b]d\mu(\omega)=x\int_\Omega a(\omega)\,d\mu(\omega)+b.$$
Since $a(\omega)>0$, we conclude that $\int_\Omega a(\omega)\,d\mu(\omega)>0$, which proves that $\mathbb E[F(x,\omega)]\to +\infty$ as $x\to+\infty$. For the case of $x\to-\infty$, just consider an affine function $a^*(\omega)x+b\le F(x,\omega)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $a^*(\omega)<0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but why such a(w) and b exist? specially I have a doubt why a(w) can be strictly positive?